# What is the method to determine the total market capitalization of the Bitcoin market?

Tags: value, market, marketplace

When I look at the following [site](https://www.coinspot.com.au/tradecoins) it says (at the time of writing) that the total market capitalization of Bitcoin is $125,927,574,809 AUD.

Now I think you could do this by running through the entire history of transactions on the blockchain, adding them all up, and multiplying by the current price. But there is probably a better way.

My question is: **What is the method to determine the total market capitalization of the Bitcoin market?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Bitcoin market cap(in AUD)" = "Number of bitcoins in circulation"   X   "Value of single bitcoin(in AUD)"

The same as a market cap of some company: "number of their shares" X "value of single share".

Market cap means what would be the money you get if you sell all the bitcoins at current price.

*Number of bitcoins in circulation can be calculated by going through all blocks of the main blockchain and sum the bitcoin reward of each of them.*

Comment: Great answer. Where do I get the number of coins in circulation?

Comment: I use this site for that kind of stuff: https://coinmarketcap.com/

Comment: Ok - I was looking for an implementation method

Comment: What do you mean by the implementation method?

Comment: I mean in terms of the BTC protocol and how the a software client and that site use it.

Comment: You can sum all the mined blocks from first one ever mined and multiply each one with the reward it gave. These are all the bitcoins that ever entered the circulation

Comment: Alternatively, and surprisingly, this is equal to the value of all unspent outputs currently on the blockchain. Because all unspent outputs show all the bitcoins in the circulation.

Comment: The sum of all unspent outputs will give you the actual amount of Bitcoin in circulation. This will be slightly less than what you calculate from mining because there are some coins that are irrevocably lost.

Comment: How can they be lost? (If keys are lost they are still on the chain as UTXOs ?)

Comment: Ok - can you please update your answer to include that?